# How to display a timer in different UIViewControllers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, singleton, nstimer

I would like to display a timer (minutes and seconds) in different viewcontrollers of my application. How can I do that ?

I was thinking to use the timer with a Singleton, but how update the right label every seconds ?

Comment: Have your timer update routine send out notifications.  Any viewController that is interested in displaying that timer can listen for the notifications and update their label.

Comment: I used this method, it works perfectly, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use singleton

This code call method `updateLabel:` every seconds

Obj-c

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Swift

```
var myTimer: NSTimer? = nil
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {     
    myTimer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.updateAmazing),
   userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateAmazing() {
    //update
}
```

In singleton you should start timer, on controller you start updating label and value get from singleton.

**IMPORTANT**

Not forget to invalidate timer.

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    myTimer.invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way - use NSNotificationCenter from Singleton
Or you can create array with delegates and call method when timer was update, all ViewControllers which in this array will receive messages